# How to configure Juniper SSG5 with VLANs and DHCP

Tags: networking, dhcp, juniper, ssg5

I just purchased a used SSG5, upgraded the firmware, and now I'd like to set it up as my Firewall/DHCP/VPN.  I'm new to Juniper, so please forgive any blatant missteps in terminology.

I am familiar and have done this setup with pFsense and Untangle.

Here is how I would like my LAN (trusted) interface configured

```
et0.2 1 10.0.0.0/24 - SSG5, cisco switch (already configured for VLAN100 and 200)
eth0.2.100 VLAN100 = 192.168.1.0/24 - secured 
eth0.2.200 VLAN200 = 192.168.2.0/24 - guest
```

I’m having issues configuring the interfaces.  Based on what I read, here is what I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAC8p.jpg

- ethernet0/0 WAN (cable modem) untrusted
- ethernet0/1 WAN2 (iphone tether backup in case WAN1 goes down) untrusted
- bgroup0  DHCP 10.0.0.1/24 (what is configured and lets me connect)
- ethernet0/2 - 0/6 part of bgroup0

I created a bgroup0.1 sub interface and configured it to VLAN100;  When I tried to also add a VLAN 100, I got a “set interface "vlan100" zone "vlan" unknown keyword vlan100”

I created bgroup0.2 and tried to have it be associated with 192.168.2.0/24  and I got the following error “ip change pre-checking failed. Interface: Illegal overlapping subnet”

**Questions:**

1. How do I configure interfaces correctly?  Do I need to add VLAN interfaces?  Should my sub interfaces be level 2 or 3?
2. I assume that after that I need to configure the DHCP servers (which should be easy)
3. Will I need to do anything to Tag the ports after?  If so, how

Thanks again!